# How to downgrade php from 5.6 to 5.5 on Fedora 21

Tags: php-5.5, php-5.6, fedora-21

I need to do the subject because I'm developing with the team on PHP 5.5, but my current Fedora version contains PHP 5.6.

I've found a Remi's repo contining [PHP 5.5 for FC-21](http://pkgs.org/fedora-21/remi-x86_64/php55-2.1-1.fc21.remi.x86_64.rpm.html), installed it as described in "Install Howto" section. But I cannot run the Apache to use with PHP v.5.5. Please suggest what I can do to have desired?

Comment: Solved by completely removing the **php** package from system and installing the **php55** package from Remi's repo. Then I've created symlinks to php55 for binary `/usr/bin/php` and for config `php55.ini <- /etc/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

you can try to downgrade your current installation using the packet manager by issuing the command `yum downgrade php55` see [downgrade or rollback updates](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29617), where you can also specify a specific version. Before that I suggest you to first verify your installation history about php if its is present.

Another way is to install the specific version you want [see the answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151689/how-can-i-instruct-yum-to-install-a-specifc-version-of-package-x) and then add a rule to block further updates in `/etc/yum.conf` [see here for the blocking rule](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10185)

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work for me because of there was no php55 package in standard repos of FC-21, so no downgrade possible.

Comment: usually centos and fedora use older versions of php, when in need of a more recent version I usually add other repos such as remi, then you can apply the second part of my answer [how to add remi's repository](http://www.unixmen.com/install-remi-repository-rhel-centos-scientific-linux-76-x5-x-fedora-201918/)